# How to add array to last array indexed inside object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, append, push

I have the following object:

```
[
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
]
```

And I wanna add a another array but just to the last array of the object, always (the first object length can change). So, it might look like this:

New array element:

```
{ name: "Hello Id 3" }
```

First object with the the second one appended:

```
[
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hello Id 3" }
]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.assign()` is one way to merge properties of two objects

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
]

const obj = { name: "Hello Id 3" };

Object.assign( data[data.length-1], obj);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Both answers are excellent, but I choose this one for it's practicality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.length` (-1) to find the index of the last object in the array and then add the elements of the new object to that:

```js
let objs = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

const name = { name: "Hello Id 3" };

const idx = objs.length - 1;
objs[idx] = { ...objs[idx], ...name };
console.log(objs);
```